# Is there an intuitive way to understand why a frequency cannot be writen as a sum of other frequencies?

Tags: trigonometry, fourier-analysis

Let's say we have a sequence of functions $(f_n)$ and for $n$, $f_n$ is a cosine at frequency $k$,  i.e. $f_n(t)=\cos(2\pi kt)$ for some $k$ which depends of $n$.

Let $n_1,\dots n_k$ be natural numbers, why can't $f_{n_1}$ be expressed as a sum of $f_{n_2},\dots,f_{n_k}$?

I know the "official" proof that involves a well chosen scalar product, but is there a more intuitive way, that even a high school student who knows circular functions could understand?

Edit: Sorry, I meant a linear combination and not a simple sum.

Comment: See this: http://www.jstor.org/stable/27642004

Comment: We have to make the restriction that all $n_k$ are distinct, non-negative integers.  The property you'd like to show is called the "linear independence" of functions of the form $f_{n_k}$.

Answer (score 1):

You could use $2\cos(2\pi k t)=\exp(2\pi i kt)+\exp(-2\pi i kt) = z^k+z^{-k}$ with $z=\exp(2\pi i t)$ to reduce the problem to the linear independence of polynomials. Is the question why $z^{n_1}+z^{-n_1}$ can't be expressed as a sum of $z^{n_2}+z^{-n_2}, \ldots,z^{n_k}+z^{-n_k}$ easier to solve? Not necessarily, but at least its solution doesn't involve a well chosen scalar product.